# How can I color a one specific item in the header menu of my web site (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

I have 6 item in my header menu but I want to make one of them red. How can I do that? Please explain more detailed because I am a lawyer....

Comment: I added an answer, but I did it on my phone. I'll add images and edit my answer when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Appearance > Menu and select the menu you're after.

Under 'Screen options' on top, check the box to show attributes.

Find your menu item and click it. You'll see the ability to add a class name. Remember what you added.

Under theme options (in the left menu) choose 'global css' and add your styling there.

`.class-name { background- color: red;}`

1. [image: Step 1]
2. [image: Add class ability]
3. [image: Add class to menu item]
4. [image: Go to customize]
5. [image: Click to edit Additional CSS]
6. [image: Add the styling]

Comment: should I add .class-name { background- color: red;} css class or title attributes?
and then should I add additional CSS in the apeearance -> customize or theme editor style.css ?

Comment: I'll update my answer to provide visual aides for you. Just finding some screenshots to make it clear. :)

Comment: great, it worked but I dont want "background" to be red, I want the word to be red.

Comment: change 'background-color' to just 'color'

Comment: Yes. :) That should do it.

Comment: try `class-name li { color: red; }`

Comment: actually `class-name a` might work better, as it'd target the link text. I prefer the list item `li` so that whether it's regular text or a link it'll style it. Try both if one doesn't work for you. :)

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: Try this : `class-name li { color: red !important; }`

Comment: When I add that code to CSS Style in the menu section it automatically delete the paranthesis. And then I paste the code in the customization-> css its not working

Comment: They're not parantheses. They're brackets { } Just copy the code I highlight and paste it in. `.class-name li { color: red; }`

Comment: Seems like you got it sorted! :)

Comment: I didn't write to make you angry... Still not working, or better; I am missing something

Comment: I would never be angry. :) I just need info to help you. What problem are you having? Can you explain the issue you're having?

Comment: I did what you say but color not changed.

Comment: I'm thinking you're doing something wrong accidentally, but I cannot find where the mistake is without seeing it. Can you take screenshots of the menu panel with the CSS class added, and the Additional CSS tab contents to see if you put it in correctly?

Comment: Change the text in the first image to 'class-name'